# Twitter Bootstrap CSS affecting Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, twitter-bootstrap, css

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap, and have a Google map.

Images on the map, such as marker are being skewed by the CSS in Bootstrap.

In the Bootstrap CSS there is:

```
img {
    border: 0 none;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

When I disable the `max-width` property using Firebug, the marker image appears as normal.
How can I prevent the Bootstrap CSS from affecting the Google maps images?

Comment: answer here:
https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/26

Answer (score 186, accepted):

With Bootstrap 2.0, this seemed to do the trick:

```
#mapCanvas img {
  max-width: none;
}
```

Comment: Make sure to add `#mapCanvas img { width: auto; display:inline; }` as mentioned below by @nodrog

Comment: From Bootstrap 2.0.3 release notes: "Fixed regression in responsive images support as of 2.0.1. We've re-added max-width: 100%; to images by default. We removed it in our last release since we had folks complaining about Google Maps integration and other projects, but we're taking a different stance now on these things and will require developers to make these tweaks on their end."

Comment: FYI: Bootstrap 2.0.4 release notes: "Added special CSS to prevent max-width: 100%; on images from messing up Google Maps rendering."

Comment: That's strange that they have finally decided to hardcode id, not use class instead

Comment: #mapCanvas didn't work for me. I just used my .map class that i used as the google maps container and it did the trick. THANKS!

Comment: didn't work for us using gmap4rails gem, but did when we changed to .map_container img {
    max-width: none;
}

.map_container label {
    width: auto; display:inline;
}

Comment: Awesome man.. For 2 projs i thought there was something wrong with google maps///:)

Comment: Essentially this also works for Gmaps4rails and Zurb Foundation: Use 
`img {
    max-width: none;
    width: auto;
    display: inline;
  }`
on .smap (the class name can be choosen via gmaps()' map_options)

Answer (score 80):

There is also an issue with the dropdown selectors for terrain and overlays, adding both these will fix the issues...

```
#mapCanvas img { 
  max-width: none;
}

#mapCanvas label { 
  width: auto; display:inline; 
}
```

The second style will sort of other issues with the terrain and overlay box in some browsers.

Comment: Yes ! everything seems fixed with this one combined with the answer flagged as "accepted" above. Thanks.

Comment: works like a charm in firefox 17 but not in chrome 23. dont know why but i found the solution just add this: `$('.map').on('shown',function(){
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
    });`

Comment: You are a genius. Thanks very much. This was driving me insane :-)

Answer (score 20):

Give your map canvas div an id of `map_canvas`.

[This bootstrap commit](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/commit/fe30bd60553bea0f706725deb9a0ad9ef04f0247) includes the `max-width: none` fix for the id `map_canvas` (but it won't work for `mapCanvas`).

Comment: I think only to change the id is necessary in v2.2.2

Comment: i cannot find such id in css file

Comment: @robd : Just for curious, Why it will not work for except map_canvas.

Comment: @ArunRaj because the fix in bootstrap is hardcoded to the #map_canvas id (see the linked commit). In any case, this answer is probably out of date now given that it's nearly 2 years old.

Answer (score 11):

None of these answers worked for me, so I went in to my div and looked at its children I saw a new div with class "gm-style", so I put this in my CSS:

```
.gm-style img {
    max-width: none;
  }

  .gm-style label {
    width: auto; display:inline;
  }
```

..and that solved the problem for me.

Comment: +1 this is the only answer that worked for me to fix the weird "zoom" controls. (Bootstrap 2)

Comment: Worked for me too. Good spotting :)

Comment: Thanks, worked for me too. The only answer that worked for me to fix the weird "zoom" controls. (with Foundation 5)

Answer (score 3):

You want to over-ride the max-width rule in the CSS section by using max-width: none; This seems to be the way around this problem

Answer (score 2):

Changing the #MapCanvas didn't work for us using gmap4rails gem, but did when we changed to

```
.map_container img {
    max-width: none;
}

.map_container label {
    width: auto; display:inline;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I am using gmaps4rails, this fix did it for me:

```
.gmaps4rails_map img {
    max-width: none;
}
.gmaps4rails_map label {
    width: auto; display:inline;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

latest twitter bootstrap 2.0.4 includes this fix directly.

If you are wrapping your content in the a (div class="container") as in the demo page of twitter bootstrap,  you should add a style="height: 100%"

Answer (score 1):

There is also an issue with printing maps using Print in any browser. The `img { max-width: 100% !important; }` will not be fixed by the code above: **you need to add an `!important` declaration like so:**

```
@media print {
  img {
    max-width: auto !important;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had to turn box-shadow off, and because of the order of my includes, I added the !important flag.

```
#mapCanvas img {
    max-width: none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

Comment: This worked for me. If you're gonna vote someone down, you should at least say why.

Answer (score 0):

All answers were max-widht:none

for me, max-height:inherit worked.....

People are using #map, #map_canvas, etc. Look at your parent div. 
If it's blue, than it will be #blue img { }