# Distorted InfoBox in Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm using Google Maps' API and added a few markers in a map. Each marker has a infoBox with different content. Everything works fine but the appearance it's just horrible.

As you can see in the following image, it looks kinda distorted. Any clues?

[image http://box.jisko.net/i/d8353364.png](http://box.jisko.net/i/d8353364.png)

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK. @geocodezip was right. Bootstrap does make a conflict with Google Maps and this was already solved here: [Twitter Bootstrap CSS affecting Google Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9141249/twitter-bootstrap-css-affecting-google-maps)

Thank you :)