# google map issue with twitter bootstrap

Tags: jquery, css, google-maps, twitter-bootstrap

I am using this http://rjshade.github.com/gmaps-autocomplete/ to plugin a map in my website.

I use twitter bootstrap, the modal that the map is viewed in causes the pin to looks buggy (with a shadow and very tiny) and inaccurate when moving it, as well as on loading the pin on the map, the pin isn't centered in the view.
once I remove the bootstrap.min.css all these bugs are fixed.

Any ideas how to fix these bugs while having the bootstrap.min.css ??
Thanks alot in advance

Map on load -- [image]

Pin -- [image]

Comment: Can you post a link to your page or create a jsfiddle with your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answer might be to add this CSS:

```
#mapCanvas img {
    max-width: none;
}
```

More here:

[Twitter Bootstrap CSS affecting Google Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9141249/twitter-bootstrap-css-affecting-google-maps)

Comment: The version of twitter bootstrap(2.1.0), has it done like so by default

Comment: Maybe try adding the above to this element '#gmaps-canvas'?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the pin problem by changing the ***id*** of the map canvas from **gmaps-canvas** to **map_canvas** in all the files.

But the problem of loading the map centered is still not fixed.