# jquery store locator plugin icon and arrow issue

Tags: jquery

Hello my problem is i dont see the arrow in the address box the way it should be seen
[image]

and it should be seen like this http://bjornblog.com/storelocator/default-location-example.html
here's my file, im using bootstrap btw

```
<div class="row-fluid">

            <div class="span12 whole-container clearfix">

                <div id="map-container" class="span12 clearfix">
                    <div id="loc-list" class="span3">
                        <ul id="list"></ul>
                    </div>
                    <div id="map" class="span9 span-no-leftmargin"></div>
                </div>

            </div><!-- ./  whole container span12-->                                                        

        </div><!-- ./ row fluid -->
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3eKaA/

any idea?
ty in advance

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution [Twitter Bootstrap CSS affecting Google Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9141249/twitter-bootstrap-css-affecting-google-maps) i think the problem with my question is that i wasnt able to explain my problem in a better way