# Google Map CSS Issue

Tags: css, google-maps, zurb-foundation

I am building a web site based on Foundation and I am using Google Maps to display some markers on it.

The problem is that I lose the map control elements from the top left (zoom in and zoom out), and I can't figure out why.

Is there a way to fix this? Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Its too hard to guess what might be wrong. Could you reproduce this in a fiddle ?

Comment: It looks like they are getting squished. This happens when the width is set to auto on the divs containing them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Twitter Bootstrap CSS affecting Google Maps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9141249/twitter-bootstrap-css-affecting-google-maps)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out the solution and it is quite simple:

```
#map img
{
    max-width : none;
}
```

Hopefully this helps someone else!