# HERE maps show blank maptiles

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, google-maps, here-api

When I'm trying to show a map using the following html/script combination:

```
<div id="map_7e0c7d1b55054dc7b95e2b542da877e8" style="height: 350px; width: 600px;"></div>

var map = new nokia.maps.map.Display(
    document.getElementById('map_7e0c7d1b55054dc7b95e2b542da877e8'), {
        zoomLevel: 10,
        center: [60.18249633040953, 5.0916092724915245],
        components: [
            new nokia.maps.map.component.Behavior(),
            new nokia.maps.map.component.ZoomBar(),
            new nokia.maps.map.component.TypeSelector(),
            new nokia.maps.map.component.ScaleBar() 
        ]
    }
);
```

I just get a gray box with the map controls:
[image]

The network log shows that some tiles are downloaded, but one is "canceled":
[image]

Does anyone have a clue about why my map won't show?
I've double-checked the `app_id` and `app_code`.
Also, the map used to work - this happened about a month ago, with no changes made on our end as far as I can see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem. Apparently Twitter Bootstrap and HERE maps doesn't play nice - [a problem that also exists with Google Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9141249/twitter-bootstrap-css-affecting-google-maps).

The solution was to add a class to the map div named `here-maps` and add the following css:

```
.here-maps img {
    max-width: none;
}
```

Comment: As of Bootstrap 3, the div height needs to be fixed as well.