# Google Maps not filling up the entire div

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I've been trying to set up google maps on my website, but it's is only showing a fraction of it, the div remains empty. A lot of solutions suggest I include the resize function, but that doesn't seem to work. Here is my code:

```
function initialize() {
    var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(42.378343, 20.427202),
        zoom: 8,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions)
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
```

Map Canvas and it's wrapping div are both set to 100% width. All help is appreciated

Heres what it looks like: [image]

Comment: Can you recreate on JSFiddle? Got a feeling could be related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9141249/twitter-bootstrap-css-affecting-google-maps

Comment: My first feeling, is that the window (or the map-canvas) is resized after initialize.  But any how, google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize"); must be written within the initialize function; otherwise map does not exist yet.

Answer (score 4):

Try to trigger resize on your map when it is fully loaded:

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function() {
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
});
```

Comment: I get the same result as before

Comment: @Granit, can you share more details about how is your code calling GMaps? Are you using any javascript lib?

Comment: Im using some jQuery to hide and show my map, but thats it. $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#flip").click(function(){
    $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
  });
});

Comment: Yes, no results either. But if i manually resize my browser to mobile and then full screen, for some reason its covering the entire div!

Answer (score 1):

I called the map resize function after the panel was supposed to open, and map got resized the way i wanted to, filling up the div.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#flip").click(function(){
        $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
    });
});
```